# AS3 Add Event Listener in For Each

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I would like to add an eventlistener to all the elements I create in a for each loop.
But apperently the eventlistener only works with the latest created element.

How do I add an Event Listener to every element created in the for each loop?

This is my code:

```
        for each(var showCase:ShowCaseItem in _bllShowCase.arrShowCase)
        {
            var listItem:ListItemShowCase = new ListItemShowCase(showCase);
            listItem.y = yPos;
            listItem.addEventListener("ITEMDELETED", refreshShowCaseItems);
            this.addChild(listItem);

            yPos += 20;

        }
```

I hope you understand my question.

Thanks, Vincent

Comment: This code looks fine to me.  Perhaps there's a bug in refreshShowCaseItems() that's causing it to only act on the last one in the array instead of the one that raised the event?

Comment: @Herms brings up a good point... maybe you can provide the refreshShowCaseItems function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing functionally wrong with this code. It should work.

The problem probably lies somewhere else.

The display list will hold a reference to each object, so the GC shouldn't clean up any of the listeners, but you can try caching each object into an array. This way you are sure there is a reference to each object outside of this code block.

```
private var _list:Array = new Array();

for each( var item:Object in list )
{
    _list.push( listItem );
}
```

Comment: You are right, DisplayList holds reference of DisplayObject so GC shouldn't collect them. No need to cache references in array. That would add more responsibility to remove reference else, there would be memory leak.

Comment: @Bhavesh.Bagadiya That may be, but I don't think it is a good idea to use the DisplayList as a reference manager. A collection of these objects are more than likely going to be needed anyway.